# vercel deployment gives Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Tags: javascript, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a github on vercel and get this error, (not sure what more details I should be giving), in this case I'm simply coping a working repo and loading it to vercel. here is the [github](https://github.com/ashbeech/moralis-poll). I tried building it on the computer and it worked fine, not sure what exactly I need to change for it to work on Vercel.

```
 Cloning github.com/gituser/git (Branch: main, Commit: f2fb480)
    Cloning completed: 1.530s
    Analyzing source code...
    Installing build runtime...
    Build runtime installed: 3.372s
    Looking up build cache...
    Build Cache not found
    Detected package.json
    Installing dependencies...
    npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
    npm WARN deprecated eth-sig-util@1.4.2: Deprecated in favor of '@metamask/eth-sig-util'
    npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-vm@2.6.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@1.7.1: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated @walletconnect/mobile-registry@1.4.0: Deprecated in favor of dynamic registry available from: https://github.com/walletconnect/walletconnect-registry
    npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
    npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@2.2.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
    npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-common@1.5.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
    npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
    npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
    npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
    npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
    npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
    npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
    npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
    npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
    npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
    npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
    npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
    > yarn@1.22.17 preinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/yarn
    > :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
    > bufferutil@4.0.6 install /vercel/path0/node_modules/bufferutil
    > node-gyp-build
    > secp256k1@4.0.3 install /vercel/path0/node_modules/secp256k1
    > node-gyp-build || exit 0
    > utf-8-validate@5.0.8 install /vercel/path0/node_modules/utf-8-validate
    > node-gyp-build
    > node-gyp-build || exit 0
    > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
    > core-js@3.20.3 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/core-js
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
    > core-js-pure@3.20.3 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/core-js-pure
    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
    > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/ejs
    > node ./postinstall.js
    > web3-shh@1.7.0 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/web3-shh
    > echo "WARNING: the web3-shh api will be deprecated in the next version"
    WARNING: the web3-shh api will be deprecated in the next version
    > web3-bzz@1.7.0 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/web3-bzz
    > echo "WARNING: the web3-bzz api will be deprecated in the next version"
    WARNING: the web3-bzz api will be deprecated in the next version
    > web3@1.7.0 postinstall /vercel/path0/node_modules/web3
    > echo "WARNING: the web3-shh and web3-bzz api will be deprecated in the next version"
    WARNING: the web3-shh and web3-bzz api will be deprecated in the next version
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.3 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN react-moralis@0.3.11 requires a peer of moralis@>=0.0.176 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-polls@1.2.0 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-polls@1.2.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.16.7 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    added 2289 packages from 1041 contributors in 92.876s
    195 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    Running "npm run build"
    > ethereum-boilerplate@0.1.0 build /vercel/path0
    > react-scripts build
    Creating an optimized production build...
    Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
    Most CI servers set it automatically.
    Failed to compile.
    src/components/Polls.js
      Line 36:5:   'getBalance' is assigned a value but never used                                                              no-unused-vars
      Line 38:5:   'nativeToken' is assigned a value but never used                                                             no-unused-vars
      Line 39:5:   'isLoading' is assigned a value but never used                                                               no-unused-vars
      Line 41:11:  'isSaving' is assigned a value but never used                                                                no-unused-vars
      Line 41:21:  'error' is assigned a value but never used                                                                   no-unused-vars
      Line 41:28:  'save' is assigned a value but never used                                                                    no-unused-vars
      Line 41:34:  'object' is assigned a value but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
      Line 47:9:   'updatePoll' is assigned a value but never used                                                              no-unused-vars
      Line 98:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'checkReg'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! ethereum-boilerplate@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the ethereum-boilerplate@0.1.0 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-01-24T17_19_29_533Z-debug.log
    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value of CI environment variable to false solved my problem.